# Best way to compact an android application with 300+ videos

Tags: android, video, codec

I want to create a new android app and this app consists in showing many video files (10 sec videos, without sound).

They are simple videos (black and white , without sound and with 10 sec), but They are more than 300 videos. I'm thinking to apply a codec or something like that, but the videos still have a big size (80-150 KB).

I also thought in split videos by frames, because the image compression is easier, but by this way the videos will have some breaks and I don't want to.

What is the best way to create an application with these requirements?

I would like the application could be played offline, so it's important to save the video files on the mobile phone, but in other hand the apps in Play store have in general 7-15 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some big apps (games usually) have small apk files and download additional content after installation. If you can, put the video files on a server and download them when the user starts the app for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a crude solution. Keep the vieos as a zipped file in asset folder. When application starts, copy that zip file to sd card, unzip it there and them use it from that place